# Finding missing timestamps between groups

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like below

```
       Timestamp        SiteID   Count
2020-01-02T05:33:05      1044     5949
2020-01-02T05:50:05      1044     177
2020-01-02T06:00:36      1020     587
2020-01-02T06:01:05      1020     367
```

I need to generate the missing timestamps per minute grouped by **SiteID**. The count for the generated timestamp can be 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy('SiteID').agg(collect_list(unix_timestamp('Timestamp')).alias('Timestamp')) \
  .withColumn('seq', sequence(col('Timestamp')[0], col('Timestamp')[1], lit(60))) \
  .withColumn('seq', explode(array_distinct(array_union('seq', 'Timestamp')))) \
  .withColumn('Timestamp', from_unixtime('seq')) \
  .drop('seq') \
  .join(df, ['SiteId', 'Timestamp'], 'left') \
  .fillna(0).show(20, False)

+------+-------------------+-----+
|SiteID|Timestamp          |Count|
+------+-------------------+-----+
|1020  |2020-01-02 06:00:36|587  |
|1020  |2020-01-02 06:01:05|367  |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:33:05|5949 |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:34:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:35:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:36:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:37:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:38:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:39:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:40:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:41:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:42:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:43:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:44:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:45:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:46:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:47:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:48:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:49:05|0    |
|1044  |2020-01-02 05:50:05|177  |
+------+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: If you want to use multiple siteId columns than code should modify a bit for join and group by columns but if you are saying multiple values, no need.